# How to extend React class in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Here is a simple example:

```
interface BaseProps {
    name: string;
}

class BaseClass<P extends BaseProps> extends React.Component<P, void> {

}

interface SuperProps {

}

class SuperClass extends BaseClass<SuperProps> {

}
```

I'm expecting that SuperClass by default would have `this.props.name`. But right now, I'm getting a compilation error, saying `Type 'SuperProps' does not satisfy the constraint 'BaseProps'.Property 'name' is missing in type 'SuperProps'.`

What am I doing wrong? I realize I can do `SuperProps extends BaseProps` but that seems redundant here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class BaseClass<P extends BaseProps> extends React.Component<P, void>
```

where `<P extends BaseProps>` means any valid type which extends `BaseProps` is assignable to `BaseClass`. This is how the generics works.

Now, when you do

```
interface SuperProps {

}

class SuperClass extends BaseClass<SuperProps> {

}
```

You are assigning the type `SuperProps` which does not extend the `BaseProps`. That is the reason you are getting the error.

To overcome the error, as you said you either need to extend the `BaseProps` interface or you can use intersection types. If you use intersection types then the complete example will look like:

```
export interface BaseProps {
    name: string;
}

class BaseClass<P> extends React.Component<P & BaseProps, void> {

}

interface SuperProps {

}

class SuperClass extends BaseClass<SuperProps> {
    render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.name} {/* Won't throw an error*/}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

You can read more about advanced-types [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

Answer (score 0):

Now say you couldn't modify `BaseClass` (3rd party code) such that it takes a generic type i.e.

```
class BaseClass extends React.Component<BaseProps, void> {

}
```

You should still be able to redefine `BaseClass` with extended prop types like so:

```
const SuperClass = BaseClass as React.ComponentClass<
  BaseProps & {
    somethingElse: string;
  }
>;
```

---

Full e.g. where `SomeInput` actually supports `autoFocus` prop but it's exported prop type defs do not:

```
import { Input as SomeInput, InputPropsType as SomeInputPropsType } from 'somewhere';

const Input = SomeInput as React.ComponentClass<
  SomeInputPropsType & {
    autoFocus?: boolean;
  }
>;

// Now passing `autoFocus` prop to `Input` should be fine
```